# The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type R.layout

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, findviewbyid

I started programming Android recently, and I have a problem.
I'm trying to get the word written in an EditText, as a string.

```
package com.example.generatoredifrasi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.R.layout;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class EditText
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); 
    EditText Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    String string = Text.getText().toString(); // get the value from the EditText
}

}
```

findViewById gives me this error: `The method findViewById (int) is undefined for the type R.layout`

why? how I solve this problem?

There is an easier way to get the word written in the EditText as a string?

Comment: We need to see the context of your code. Put where you are (Fragment, Activity, etc), and who do you get that layout var.

Comment: Aside from the main scope of this problem, you shouldn't be putting any code in a standard Java main method. The main method doesn't exist per se in Android - as a beginner, you should be putting code like this in the onCreate method of an Activity or the onCreateView method of a Fragment.

Comment: 1. Don't call your class "EditText", name it something like "MainActivity". 2. Your class needs to extend `Activity`. (see my updated answer)

Answer (score 2):

The first error you are experiencing "The method findViewById (int) is undefined for the type R.layout" is because you have `import R;` in your imports, so `layout` is actually `R.layout`, not your layout View.  If `layout` were a reference to a view, `findViewById()` would be a valid method call.

The next error, "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Generatore" looks to be because your class `Generatore` does not inherit from `Activity`, therefore there is no `findViewById()` method available.

Without seeing your entire class, its hard to say for sure where your problem is. This is the bare minimum required to get the String value of your EditText:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); 
        EditText Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        String string = Text.getText().toString(); // get the value from the EditText
    }
}
```

Of course, you probably want to fetch the text after the user inputs, maybe within a button click or something, so you can move `Text.getText().toString()` elsewhere, as long as it comes after the `setContentView()` and `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 1):

The method name `findViewById()` suggests that you provide the **id** of a view and not a **layout**. Therefore use an id you have added *within* your layout file.

Should look like this: `findViewById(R.id.my_mega_awesome_view);`

Update:

The way you try to get the entered text is correct. I guess your problem is that you need to find the right place and time to get the data. I mean the user has to type something into it before it makes sense to get it. Try reading about the [addTextChangedListener() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))

Comment: It depends on the situation. If the user fills out fields and eventually presses a "Submit" button, then there's no need to listen for every change, so a getText() would work fine. However, there are certainly cases where a TextChangedListener works best as well.

Comment: @naweinberger I agree.

Comment: I need the getText () then, but gives me a lot of errors

Comment: `a lot of errors` is not a good problem description. You should check the answer from invertigo, his is the most complete one. You should start with reading the fundamentals when you really thought that the main method is the place to start.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mention layout.findViewById(R.id.EditText); You can simply refer the id of view i.e EditText view.

```
EditText Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
String string = Text.getText().toString();
```

Comment: done, but it gives me this error

The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Generatore

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in a fragment, you should be calling `findViewById` as a function of a view.

You'll need to first inflate the view by calling

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
```

in your `onCreate` method.

Then you can find views on the page by calling

```
view.findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
```

Make sure to `return view;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import `android.R.layout`.
Under normal circumstances, you should never have to import any R classes.